# Input does not submit the form on change

Tags: javascript, jquery, date, input, datepicker

I have a problem with "on change" input.
What it's supposed to do is that on click it shows datepicker, but when you pick a date to submit, input change function does not work.
Please, run a code snippet below.

```js
if (top.location != location) {
  top.location.href = document.location.href;
}
$(function() {
  window.prettyPrint && prettyPrint();
  $('#dp1').datepicker({
    format: 'yyyy-mm-dd'
  });

  $('#dpYears').datepicker();
  $('#dpMonths').datepicker();
});
```

```html
<link href="http://www.eyecon.ro/bootstrap-datepicker/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="http://www.eyecon.ro/bootstrap-datepicker/css/datepicker.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://www.eyecon.ro/bootstrap-datepicker/js/bootstrap-datepicker.js"></script>

<div data-date-format="yyyy-mm-dd">
  <form id="date" method="POST" action="index.php">
    <input type="text" name="date" class="span2" value="2016-08-07" id="dp1" style="text-align: center; width: 50%; background-color: #5a95f5; border: none;">
  </form>
</div>

<script>
  $('input[id="dp1"]').change(function() {
    $('#date1').submit();
  });
</script>
```

Comment: You are calling `submit()` on `#date1`? Should it not be `#date`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is your input doesn't fire the `change()` function when you select the date. What you can do is use the events for the datepicker in this case the [changeDate](http://bootstrap-datepicker.readthedocs.io/en/latest/events.html#changedate)

```js
if (top.location != location) {
  top.location.href = document.location.href;
}
$(function() {
  window.prettyPrint && prettyPrint();
  $('#dp1').datepicker({
    format: 'yyyy-mm-dd'
  });

  $('#dpYears').datepicker();
  $('#dpMonths').datepicker();
});
```

```html
<link href="http://www.eyecon.ro/bootstrap-datepicker/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="http://www.eyecon.ro/bootstrap-datepicker/css/datepicker.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://www.eyecon.ro/bootstrap-datepicker/js/bootstrap-datepicker.js"></script>

<div data-date-format="yyyy-mm-dd">
  <form id="date" method="POST" action="index.php">
    <input type="text" name="date" class="span2" value="2016-08-07" id="dp1" style="text-align: center; width: 50%; background-color: #5a95f5; border: none;">
  </form>
</div>

<script>
  $('#dp1').on('changeDate', function () {
    console.log('Date Selected')
  })
</script>
```

Comment: Wow, It works. I just replaced     console.log('Date Selected')      with    $('#date').submit(); Thank you so much!

Comment: glad to help U @joni

Answer (score 0):

Simple you can use this code:

```
$('#input-date')
.datepicker()   
.on('changeDate', function(e){    
    $('#formID').submit();
});
```